# Adding Google and Facebook login authentication for Spring boot and Reactjs fullstack application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

So I wanted add a functionality to my existing full-stack application for pet project, so I was wonder what I need to add in my spring security application that my configuration and so. I don't know but I stuck really hard. I know I need to use 2Auth request , and get credentials from response.
so what I want is that I want to be able to authorize from my react application and it has two buttons Google and Facebook respectively:

```
export default function LoginForm({ onLogin, onRegister }) {
    const [type, toggle] = useToggle(['login', 'register']);
    let [testAuth, setTestAuth] = useState('');

    const form = useForm({
        initialValues: {
            firstName: '',
            email: '',
            login: '',
            password: '',
            terms: true,
        },

        validate: {
            email: (val) => (/^\S+@\S+$/.test(val) ? null : 'Invalid email'),
            password: (val) => (val.length <= 2 ? 'Password should include at least 6 characters' : null),
        },
    });

    const setGoogle = () => {
        setTestAuth('google');
        console.log(testAuth)
    }
    const setFacebook = () => {
        setTestAuth("facebook")
        console.log(testAuth)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (type === 'login') {
            const { login, password } = form.values;
            onLogin(login, password);
        } else if (type === 'register') {
            const { firstName, email, login, password } = form.values;
            onRegister(firstName, email, login, password);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Paper radius="md" p="xl">
            <Text size="lg" weight={500} ta="center">
                Welcome, {type} with
            </Text>

            <Group grow mb="md" mt="md">
                <Button radius="xl" onClick={setGoogle}><IconBrandGoogle /></Button>
                  <Button radius="xl" onClick={setFacebook}><IconBrandFacebook /></Button>
            </Group>

            <Divider label={`Or continue with ${type}`} labelPosition="center" my="lg" />

            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Stack>
                    {/*{testAuth === 'google' && (*/}
                    {/*    <FacebookLoginComponent />*/}
                    {/*)}*/}
                    {testAuth === 'facebook' && (
                        <Text>it is a FACEBOOK</Text>
                    )}
                    {type === 'register' && (
                        <>
                            <TextInput
                                label="Name"
                                placeholder="Your name"
                                value={form.values.firstName}
                                onChange={(event) => form.setFieldValue('firstName', event.currentTarget.value)}
                                radius="md"
                            />

                            <TextInput
                                required
                                label="Email"
                                placeholder="hello@mantine.dev"
                                value={form.values.email}
                                onChange={(event) => form.setFieldValue('email', event.currentTarget.value)}
                                error={form.errors.email && 'Invalid email'}
                                radius="md"
                            />
                        </>
                    )}

                    <TextInput
                        required
                        label="Login"
                        placeholder="Your login"
                        value={form.values.login}
                        onChange={(event) => form.setFieldValue('login', event.currentTarget.value)}
                        error={form.errors.login && 'Invalid login'}
                        radius="md"
                    />

                    <PasswordInput
                        required
                        label="Password"
                        placeholder="Your password"
                        value={form.values.password}
                        onChange={(event) => form.setFieldValue('password', event.currentTarget.value)}
                        error={form.errors.password && 'Password should include at least 6 characters'}
                        radius="md"
                    />

                    {type === 'register' && (
                        <Checkbox
                            label="I accept terms and conditions"
                            checked={form.values.terms}
                            onChange={(event) => form.setFieldValue('terms', event.currentTarget.checked)}
                        />
                    )}
                </Stack>

                <Group position="apart" mt="xl">
                    <Anchor
                        component="button"
                        type="button"
                        color="dimmed"
                        onClick={() => toggle()}
                        size="xs"
                    >
                        {type === 'register'
                            ? 'Already have an account? Login'
                            : "Don't have an account? Register"}
                    </Anchor>
                    <Button type="submit" radius="xl">
                        {upperFirst(type)}
                    </Button>
                </Group>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

I have a controller to create a user and login it , now it looks like this, and I create and login using axios request from reactjs

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> login(@RequestBody @Valid CredentialsDto credentialsDto) {
        UserDto userDto = userService.login(credentialsDto);
        userDto.setToken(userAuthenticationProvider.createToken(userDto.getLogin()));
        System.out.println("Entered as for DTO: " + userDto.getLogin() + " as credentials: " + credentialsDto.getLogin());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto);
    }

    


    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> register(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpDto user) {
        UserDto createdUser = userService.register(user);
        createdUser.setToken(userAuthenticationProvider.createToken(user.getLogin()));
        //TODO validate user's login if there is same or not
        System.out.println("USER for: " + user.getLogin() + " " + " for token: " + createdUser.getLogin());
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/users/" + createdUser.getId())).body(createdUser);
    }
```

but my Security Configuration look like this

```
package com.example.jwtbackend.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@ComponentScan
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    private final UserAuthenticationEntryPoint userAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private final UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling) ->
                        exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(userAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthenticationProvider),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/products**", "/products/**", "/create", "/",
                                "/myproducts/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {
                    oauth2.loginPage("/test").permitAll();
                });
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

And User entry point

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), new ErrorDto("Unauthorized path"));
    }
}
```

Provider

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationProvider {
    
    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        // this is to avoid having the raw secret key available in the JVM
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String login) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + 3600000); // 1 hour

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);
        return JWT.create()
                .withIssuer(login)
                .withIssuedAt(now)
                .withExpiresAt(validity)
                .sign(algorithm);
    }

    public Authentication validateToken(String token) {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);

        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .build();

        DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);

        UserDto user = userService.findByLogin(decoded.getIssuer());

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList());
    }

}
```

I also added this to my application properties with right instances

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id={Deleted for brevity}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret={Deleted for brevity}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-id={Deleted for brevity}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-{Deleted for brevity}
frontend.url=http://localhost:3000
```

So my question is that, what I need to add my React and spring boot application that I will be able to authenticated using google sign in and facebook sign in..

The trouble is that I can't really wrap my head around and I am quite confused